# Mimic deluser command in linux

Tags: command-line, c, user-management, passwd, shadow

To delete a user without deluser in linux we have to do these things

1. Remove user from etc/passwd
2. Remove user from etc/shadow
3. Remove user's directory from /home/
   (I used sudo rm -rf /home/username)

I tried many ways to remove user from etc/passwd and etc/shadow but nothing worked is it possible to do this thing without deluser .

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Why would you do it without deluser? Why removing from `/etc/passwd` "is not possible"?

Comment: Yes I am using ubuntu . I was trying to mimic deluser .Can u tell me how to remove it from etc/passwd and etc/shadow please.

Comment: What do you mean by `mimic deluser`? Regarding removing from `/etc/passwd`, there is no problem to remove a line from there using any text editor.

Comment: I was trying to writing a c program for mimicking deluser using command line arguments . I didn't get how to remove it using text editor .

Comment: Thanks user3629249

Comment: What do you mean by "I didn't get how to remove it using text editor "? Open the file with any text editor and remove the line with corresponding user. And I don't know what "mimicking" means in your case.

Comment: You can use some shell programs like `grep`, `awk`, etc to do it programmatically. You can do it directly from C too.

Comment: @user3629249 Why would you chown to root if you remove a user. It is crap.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pilot6 but in this process I used sudo gedit/etc/passwd also btw thanks a lot dude saved my time.

Comment: here is the directory listing for `passwd`  `-rw-r--r--   1 root root     2566 May  7 13:07 passwd`  Note that only the `root` user can modify that file.  So opening that file in any ol' text editor is not sufficient.

Comment: to start, You must be 'root'. Depending on the options passed to `deluser`, it might delete the users' home directory.  It might removed all files owned by that user.  It might remove all files in a specific group.  It might remove all mail files for that user, and much more.  Duplicating its' functionality would be a major undertaking.  Better to use the `deluser` command.

Comment: @Pilot6,  Lets be careful of the language you use.  Your 4 letter word is not appreciated.